# execute geolocate javascript before form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

Im trying to execute some jquery before a form is submitted.

The aim is to obtain user location, and save the coordinates before the form gets posted.

but it happens too quickly and doesn't seem like it is being fully executed.
the popup for sharing location shows for a split second the the form posts before i can answer yes to sharing location

```
$("#DepotSearchForm").submit(function () {


        // your code here

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    $('#Latitude').val(position.coords.latitude);
                    $('#Longitude').val(position.coords.longitude);
                    alert(position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude);
                    //gmap.setCenter(pos);
                }, function () {
                    //alert("Unable to determine location");
                    //return false;
                });
            } 

    //  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geolocation` is asynchronous so indeed your form is being submitted before it completes.

Choices would be to set the location values when page loads or you can prevent the jQuery submit event and use the native submit when the geolocation has completed.

```
$("#DepotSearchForm").submit(function(event) {
  // prevent jQuery submit occurrung
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = this;    

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

      $('#Latitude').val(position.coords.latitude);
      $('#Longitude').val(position.coords.longitude);
      alert(position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude);

      // tigger native submit
      form.submit();

    }, function() {
       // handle geolocation error
    });
  }
});
```

You should also do something in UI to indicate form is being processed and prevent user from submitting again while geolocation is being processed